# Proprietary handling/collecting of user defined errors

Tags: error-handling, f#

I do not know how to implement a proprietary handling procedure of user defined errors (routines/algorithm stop) or  warnings messages (routine/algorithm can proceed) without using Exceptions (i.e. failwith .... Standard System Exception).

Example: I have a Module with a series of Functions that uses a lot of input data to be checked and to be used to calculate the thickness of a Pressure Vessel Component.

The calculation procedure is complex, iterative and there are a lot of checks to be performed before getting a result, check that can generate "User Defined Errors" that stop the procedure/routine/algorithm or generate a "Warning Messages" proceeding on.

I need to collect these Errors and Messages to be shown to the User in a dedicated form (Wpf or Windows form). This later at the end.

Note: every time that I read a books of F# or C# or Visual basic or an Article in Internet, I found the same Phylosophy/Warning: raise of System/User-Defined Exception should be limited as much as possible: Exception are for unmanageable Exceptional Events ( not predictable) and cause "overload" to the Computer System.

I do not know which handling philosophy to implement. I'm confused. Limited sources available on internet on this particular argument.

Actually I'm planning to adopt this Phylosophy , taken from: "https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part2/". It sounds good for me, ... complex, but good. No other references I was able to go find on this relevant argument.

Question: there are other Phylosophies that I can consider to create this Proprietary handling/collecting of user defined errors? Some books to read or some articles?

My decision will give a big impact on how to design and write my code (splitting problem in several functions, generate a "motor" that run in sequence functions or compose then in different ways depending on results, where to check for Errors/Warnings, how to store Errors and Warning Messages to understand what is going on or where "Errors/Warnings" are genetate and caused "By Which Function"?).

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that the solution proposed by Scott Wlaschin (https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop/) is the best solution for a FUNCTIONAL LANGUAGE like F#, even if it is not so immediate. Even if I fell me like a "bear" (see https://vimeo.com/113707214), I also presume that it is the only way!

Comment: Take a look inside: "Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Result" ... there there is the Railway Oriented Programming (BASIC) already implemented! A surprise!!!

Comment: See: https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Core/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The F# way is to encode the errors in the types as much as possible. The easiest example is an option type where you would return `None` if the operation failed ans `Some value` when it succeeded. Surprisingly, very often this is enough! If not, then you can encode different types of errors AND a success "state" in a discriminated union, e.g.

```
[<Measure>]
type psi

type VesselPressureResult =
    | PressureOk
    | WarningApproachingLimit
    | ErrorOverLimitBy of int<psi>
```

and then you will use pattern matching to "decide" what to do in each case. If you need to add more variants, e.g. `ErrorTooLow`, then you would add that to the DU and then the compiler will "tell" you about all places where you need to fix the logic.

Here is the perfect source with detailed information: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/series/designing-with-types.html